# Solr thread locking (deadlock) while Indexing leads to slow Indexing

Tags: solr, locking, deadlock

I am trying to Index my file in solr and my solr data is about 15gb. 
While Indexing my file the threads locks up leading to time taken in Index updating up to 15 mins. I cant find the source of the locking, but it seems like a deadlock. But here is the stack trace.

```
 "http-26300-Processor17" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d56800 nid=0x34d6 waiting on condition [0x00007f860acfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00007f865f7b90f8> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:838)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:248)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:439)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

one more thread stack trace

```
    "pool-6-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe8944ee800 nid=0x6b65 waiting on condition [0x00007fe8925cb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00007fe8bd4c1900> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:838)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:248)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:439)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2$CommitTracker.run(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:602)
    - locked <0x00007fe8ad6ed8b0> (a org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2$CommitTracker)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be unnecessary contention, but if the operation ends, this means that there is no deadlock.

Looking at [the code of DirectUpdateHandler2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.5.0/org/apache/solr/update/DirectUpdateHandler2.java#435), it looks like this stack is due to the fact that you ask for a searcher to be warmed after your commit/optimize operation. You should check that you don't commit/optimize too often (one commit in the end is probably enough, optimize is not recommended anymore) and/or stop [waiting for a searcher to be warmed before returning](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22).